# Rdlc Report Column visibility in Export

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, rdlc, rdl

I Have One Rdl Report As Par Client Requirement I Want To Hide Some Columns In Exporting Report 
They Should Display Only Run Time Not In Export

plz help me for Export CSV

I can try all of thing but not working yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Can Find The Solution Of This Situation But Not Working In Export CSV File

1 ) I Install SqlServer R2 So Get One Paramete Like Reander.name Using This Parameter I Can Hide Specific Column Or Row
 but It Should Working In PDF And Excel not In Csv File